# write back cache on network scsi disks

Tags: iscsi, scsi

I have a machine in the cloud which has a persistent disk. For the host, it appears as a SCSI disk. I see the following seting:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/device/scsi_disk/0\:0\:1\:0/cache_type
write back
```

What does this mean? Does it mean that on this machine, there is a write back cache being used by the scsi layer and so a write I/O op might be just making it to this cache before   being deemed to be complete? (and later somehow get flushed to the actual disk across the network asyncronously)

Thanks.

Comment: That is what it means. I would also interpret it to mean "ok for temporary usage, don't put a database on it".

Comment: @GregAskew databases often are smart and issue write barriers (to ensure the data reached the target, not just the cache), so it should be safe to use for databases too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It may be safe to use for a database if the disk is on a controller with battery backed caching or it might not be a single disk at all but rather a SAN. In both cases you shouldn't be using the default IO scheduler. OTOH it might be a virtual disk on a SATA drive plugged directly into the host - in which case there is a good chance that things could go very pear shaped in the event of a sudden power outage.

But most cloud providers won't tell you that much about the hardware.

Comment: The `write back` setting is on the SCSI initiator machine.  So, what is the significance of whether the controller (i.e on the remote SCSI target machine) has a  battery or not? The said write back cache is on the initiator machine iiuc , (is that right?) and so data is going  to be cached on the initiator side itself and so suspect to loss.